# Apache Tomcat 8.5 Pool Threads Never Killed

Tags: java, tomcat, jira, threadpool, tomcat8

Specifically, we are running Atlassian Jira 8.2, which is using Tomcat 8.5. The issue we are encountering is that the generic pool threads (pool-thread-1-1 etc...) are being kept alive, and the amount continues to increase. The connector we are using is AJP, and those threads are perfectly within our set limits. That sits at about 36, and seems to be normal.

For the pool threads, each stack trace is exactly identical (for each of the now 160 threads):

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <33d81f64> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

We've already modified the server.xml for the max AJP threads, and the dbconfig.xml for the database. We cannot find out where to make a modification so that these threads timeout or reach a max.

What exactly are these threads, and where can we set limits on the amount of these threads?

Any help or insight would be appreciated!